# Terminology for the property $f(2x) = 2f(x)$

Tags: functions, terminology

The property $$f(2x) = 2f(x)$$ is strictly weaker than linearity: linearity implies it, but if e.g. $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ then $f$ can satisfy this property without being linear, as exemplified by OEIS [A006519](//oeis.org/A006519): $x \to 2^{\nu_2(x)}$.

Does this property have a name?

Comment: Homogeneous of degree 1.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens No, because the question is only about the property $f(2x)=2f(x)$, not the property $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$ for any nonzero $\alpha$.

Comment: I'd be happy with a term for the slightly stronger property $\exists \alpha: \forall x: f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$, but $\forall \alpha, x: f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$ is much stronger.

Comment: Another interpretation is $f(x+x) = f(x)+f(x)$, a sort of additivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $\alpha$, let $M_\alpha$ be the commutative monoid formed by the powers of $\alpha$ under multiplication.

Any set $X$ such that if $x \in X$ then $\alpha x \in X$ can be seen as an $M_\alpha$-set in which the action is multiplication.

Then, a function $f \colon X \to X$ such that $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$ is simply an $M_\alpha$-endomorphism.

Comment: But $f(x) =\alpha$ is also an $M_\alpha$-endomorphism, so that doesn't characterise functions which satisfy that functional equation.

Comment: No, $f(x) = \alpha$ is not an $M_\alpha$-endomorphism unless $\alpha$ is $0$ or $1$. From the functional equation $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$ we get that $f(\alpha^n x) = \alpha^n f(x)$ for any $n > 0$, and so $f(m x) = m f(x)$ for any $m \in M_\alpha$, which is exactly what it means for $f$ to be an $M_\alpha$-endomorphism.

Comment: Do you have a reference which defines the term in the sense in which you're using it? What I'm getting from Mathworld and Wikipedia is that any function $f: X \to X$ is an endomorphism.

Comment: You can check Bourbaki's _Algebra I_, chapter 1, §5.1 Monoid operating on a set, definitions 1 and 2.

Comment: Another possible name is _equivariance_ (with respect to $\alpha$), if we borrow the term from group theory (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map#Formalization) for the definition).

Comment: Thanks for the Bourbaki reference. They offer some alternatives: *mapping compatible with the operations of $M$* seems less liable to misinterpretation. I think I'll use something like "*mapping compatible with doubling*".